# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_node'

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, pycharm

I've been doing some training in data structures and i'm implementing linked list. here's the code:

```
def insertEnd(self, data):

        if self.head is None:
            self.insertStart(data)
            return

        new_node = Node(data)
        self.counter += 1
        actual_node = self.head

        while actual_node is not None:
            actual_node = actual_node.next_node

        actual_node.next_node = new_node
```

after i try to insert the second node i get this error. i dont know what's the problem

Comment: After the loop, `actual_node` must be `None`. Therefore, it can't have a `next_node` attribute.

Comment: You have assigned `None` to `actual_node` with `actual_node = actual_node.next_node`. Only at that point the `while` loop ends. Ergo, `actual_node` is **always** going to be `None` by the time you are at the last line.

Comment: Maybe what you want is `while actual_node.next_node is not None:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In while condition, you should check next node is None. That means current node is the last node. And the new node should be appended after it.

```
while actual_node.next_node is not None:
```